# Is a single Windows 10 license sufficient to native boot multiple differencing VHDs with a single parent VHD containing the Windows installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, license, licensing

Windows 10 would only be installed into the single parent VHD, all others are just differencing VHDs. This is using native boot, not VMs.

Comment: You would only be able to run a single instance at a time.  What specifically about the [EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_English.htm) for Windows 10 are you confused about with relation to to your question?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes only a single instance at any given time. I would just like to know whether this is within the EULA.

Comment: I linked you to the EULA for Windows 10.

Comment: Wait.... I didn't think that you could boot off of a differencing VHD !?!?!

Comment: @egray I believe you can as long as the VHDs are on the same disk.

Comment: This is what I'm wondering myself, running into the same scenario